# Can Geoserver have z?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, z-value

Is there a concept of a Z value or "altitude" associated with each point of a polygon that can be exposed with WFS in GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer can deliver XYZ coordinates if the source data contains Z values. You can make a try by converting the demo shapefile "states.shp" into XYZ shapefile with GDAL:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" states_3d.shp states.shp -nlt MULTIPOLYGONZ
```

Next make a new store and layer from this states_3d shapefile and make test request with WFS

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:states_3d&maxFeatures=1&outputformat=JSON
```

The result looks like

> {"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":49,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"states_3d.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-88.071564,37.51099000000001,0],[-88.087883,37.476273000000006,0],...

The Z coordinates are included.

**Note:** There is probably a bug with XYZ shapefiles and WFS 1.1.0 using GML 3 as output. This request:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:states_3d&maxFeatures=1
```

sends out GML which looks invalid because srsDimension="3" but the posList does not contain the Z values.

```
<gml:MultiSurface srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="3">
<gml:surfaceMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:exterior>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:posList>37.51099 -88.071564 37.476273 -88.087883 37.442852 ...
```